# Magento 2: Extend place order mutation

Tags: magento2

I have tried this
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Mutation {
placeOrder(input: PlaceOrderInput): PlaceOrderOutput @resolver(class: "\\Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\PlaceOrder")
}

input PlaceOrderInput {
    cart_id: String!
    anonymousId: String
}
```

Request:

```
mutation {
  placeOrder(
    input: {
      cart_id: "6tGj0vqL9VZ5FhyIySaHSIUaqmEFbyHm",
      anonymousId: "6tGj0vqL9VZ5FhyIySaHSIUaqmEFbyHm"
    }
  ) {
    order {
      order_number
    }
  }
}
```

But its not working with error **Unknown argument "anonymousId" on field "placeOrder" of type "Mutation**

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Make sure you run compile command after this change. Check with Altair tool once. I have tried the similar case with mutation "createEmptyCart" and it works fine..

Comment: I have just run cache clean, let me check after  run compile command

Comment: Thanks @PratikNavapara, for the comment, let me check

Comment: anonymous_id vs anonymousId?